# Populating reference tables at Compile Time using Templates

Tags: c++, templates

I need to generate reference tables at compile time, so that i can save some runtime calculation, say i have usecase as follows

```
static unsigned long long int table[21]={0,1,1};


template<long long N>
struct fib  
{
        static long long value()
        {
            fib<N-1>::value();
            table[N] = table[N-1] + table[N-2];         
        }
};

template<>
struct fib<0>
{
        static long long value()
        {
            return table[0];
        }
};

template<>
struct fib<1>
{
        static long long value()
        {
            return table[1];
        }
};


template<>
struct fib<2>
{
        static long long value()
        {
            return table[2];
        }
};


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fib<20>::value();  // <<----  WARNING!

    for(int i=0 ;i <21 ; ++i)
        cout<<" "<<i<<":" << table[i];
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

It results in warning

fibs.cpp: In static member function ‘static long long int fib::value()’:
fibs.cpp:12:3: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

which is correct.

My question is, Why nobody else used this way, drawbacks? and what would be other possible ways?
Resources would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use enum {value = } in your template structs.
For Example,

```
template <int N>
struct Fibonacci
{
    enum
    {
        value = Fibonacci<N-1>::value + Fibonacci<N-2>::value
    };
};
```

or

```
template <int N>
struct Fibonacci
{
    static const long long value = Fibonacci<N-1>::value + Fibonacci<N-2>::value
};
```

This link may be helpful:
[Getting template metaprogramming compile-time constants at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908256/getting-template-metaprogramming-compile-time-constants-at-runtime)

Comment: enums are by default "int", i intent to work on more complex use case which operate on char, pointers and long long. so using enum would not help in all case :(

Comment: @Mahesh consider having a look at [boost::mpl](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html), boost::mpl::string and the [static rational](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/units/static_rational.hpp)

Comment: @Mahesh How about declaring static const type? (I've just added)
or computing values in constructor of template structure will not make warning.

Comment: @SangHeonLee According to specification this type of "static" statements are not ordered. i mean to say   static const value = fib<N>::value followed by something           static const valueRad = value % 10.

Comment: @Mahesh Ok, now I understand why you need a such result table. Finbonacci example made me confused :(