# Is there a way to give dynamically values to to a templated function in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

The "hello, world" of template meta-programming can be considered the factorial code:

```
template <unsigned int n>
struct factorial {
    enum { value = n * factorial<n - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

So we can get the factorial by doing

```
cout << factorial<4>::value << endl; //It will print 24
```

But if I do:

```
int N = 4;
cout << factorial<N>::value << endl; //COMPILE ERROR
```

Is there a way to give dynamically values to a templated function in C++?

Comment: There are a few tricks you can apply. [See this post for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908256/getting-template-metaprogramming-compile-time-constants-at-runtime). [This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hErD6WGqPlA) also describes an even better solution, though for a different problem.

Comment: Also: there are a lot of people downvoting this post for inadequately explained reasons. The question seems legit.

Comment: @Xirema: If you want to evaluate a template at compile time, based on a value given at runtime, you need a time machine. If that isn't immediately clear, you shouldn't be sitting in front of a computer.

Comment: @IInspectable I advise you look at the links I provided, as you'll see that's *not* what they're doing. They're simply providing O(1) access to the values at runtime.

Comment: @Xirema: Retrieving the result of a function with linear complexity with O(1) necessitates, that the value cannot be calculated at runtime.

Comment: @IInspectable Well of course it can't be *calculated* at runtime at O(1). Doesn't mean it can't be *retrieved* at runtime in O(1) (calculated at compile-time), which would satisfy the requirements of the OP.

Comment: @Xirema: So if you need to look up a the result for a value not known until runtime, you will have to precalculate **all** values. Unless you have an infinite amount of memory, this isn't feasible.

Comment: OP, do you just want to retrieve values from a computation at both compile and run time? Placing runtime values into compile time constructs is infeasible and placing compile time values into runtime constructs will have the result calculated at runtime, but `constexpr` functions may be evaluated at compile and run time.

Comment: @IInspectable For a factorial program, that's ludicrously easy. I've provided a solution below.

Comment: @Xirema: It should also be ludicrously easy to assume, that `factorial` is just an example. This won't work in general (unless you have an infinite amount of memory, a compiler with infinite template recursion depth, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<utility>

//Only >=c++14 supports doubles in constexpr, so we're sticking to integers.
template<unsigned int I>
struct FAC {
    static constexpr uint64_t val = I * FAC<I-1>::val;
};

template<>
struct FAC<0> {
    static constexpr uint64_t val = 0;
};

template<>
struct FAC<1> {
    static constexpr uint64_t val = 1;
};

template<size_t ... I>
uint64_t factorial_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, const unsigned int i) {
    constexpr std::array<uint64_t, sizeof...(I)> a = {FAC<I>::val...};

    return a[i];
}

uint64_t factorial(const unsigned int i) {
    return factorial_impl(std::make_index_sequence<22>(), i); //Can't store factorial values above index 22 without using floating-point values
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Which factorial do you want? [1-22]: ";
    unsigned int index = 0;
    std::cin >> index;
    std::cout << "Value of " << index << " is " << factorial(index) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you'd rather it work with doubles, you'll need a c++14-compliant compiler, but this slight modification should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<array>
#include<utility>

template<unsigned int I>
struct FAC {
    static constexpr double val = I * FAC<I-1>::val;
};

template<>
struct FAC<0> {
    static constexpr double val = 0;
};

template<>
struct FAC<1> {
    static constexpr double val = 1;
};

template<size_t ... I>
double factorial_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>, const unsigned int i) {
    constexpr std::array<double, sizeof...(I)> a = {FAC<I>::val...};

    return a[i];
}

double factorial(const unsigned int i) {
    return factorial_impl(std::make_index_sequence<170>(), i); //Values above 170 are infinite.
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Which factorial do you want? [1-170]: ";
    unsigned int index = 0;
    std::cin >> index;
    std::cout << "Value of " << index << " is " << factorial(index) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot do that. The whole point of template meta-programming is to do some computation at compile-time. The entire recursive chain of expansions from your factorial example is done by the compiler, so it must know the value of `n` in order to complete the computation.

When you do not know the value of `n` until runtime, the "regular" style of programming applies, so the invocation `factorial<N>::value` becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can is this:

```
constexpr int N = 4;
std::cout << factorial<N>::value << std::endl;
```

But you won't be able to modify `N` at run-time, so I guess it doesn't help much more than for a small example.