# How to use "type ... pack-name" parameter pack in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

The [cppreference page on parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) states there is a parameter pack like this:

```
type ... pack-name(optional)    (1)
```

But how do you use it?

This doesn't work and the error is syntactical:

```
template<int... Ints>
int sum_2_int(Ints... args)
{
    return (int)(args + ...);
}
```

I can't figure out how to use this thing from the description and I don't see an example of the usage anywhere on that page. I may have just skipped it because I am very inexperienced in this part of c++.

**EDIT1:**
I am not trying to sum an arbitrary amount of integers or whatever types. I've written this function because of my complete lack of understanding of how and where to use this type of parameter pack since I assumed it will be similar to the type (2) `typename|class ... pack-name(optional)`.

**EDIT2:** Now I know that trying to use `Ints... args` as a parameter in function definition is futile. I made a new snippet, that works now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74332699/5202246). If you know more examples of the usage of this type of parameter pack, please share.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the non-type template argument form here instead of using `typename... Ints`?

Comment: With `template<int... Ints>`, `Ints` is not a bunch of types, it's a bunch of `int` values. You are trying to use `Ints` as a type; that doesn't make sense. What `sum_2_int` is supposed to be doing? How do you expect to call it?

Comment: The usage in `template<int... Ints>` is correct and uses the referenced syntax, but it just doesn't make sense to then use `Ints` as a type in the function parameter list. `Ints` is a pack of `int`s.

Comment: E.g. [`std::integer_sequence<int, Ints...>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what I've learned about type (1) parameter pack:

1. It is INCORRECT to use as a parameter in the function definition, since `template<int... Ints> int foo(...) {...}` just means that you should later use your function as `int i = foo<1,2,3,4,...>(...);`
2. It can be used as an argument to some function after the expansion happens:

```
// parameter pack type [2] typename|class ... pack-name(optional)
template <typename... Types>
int sum_to_int(Types... args)
{
    return (int)(args + ...); // fold expression used here
}

// parameter pack [1] type ... pack-name(optional)
template <int... Ints>
int sum_ints_statically()
{
    return sum_to_int(Ints...);
}

int main()
{
    return sum_ints_statically<1,2,3,4,5>(); // will return 15!
}
```

Thanks [Evg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg) and [user17732522](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17732522/user17732522) for helping me to find the answer.

Please add more usage examples if you know more!

Comment: I understand that this example is completely moronic, but it shows the possible usage of this type of the parameter pack

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function is meant to sum a list of ints. You can provide this list directly with a non-type template parameter pack and no normal parameter or with a type template parameter pack used for the normal parameter types. Not both at the same type. Examples:

```
template<int... Ints>
int sum_2_int()
{
    return (int)(Ints + ...);
}

sum_2_int<1, 2, 3>(); // template arguments must be known at compile time
```

```
template<typename... Ints>
int sum_2_int(Ints... args)
{
    return (int)(args + ...);
}

sum_2_int(1, 2, 3); // function arguments must be summable
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6j3878rE9)

Note that the second version accepts any type for each of the parameters, but you can constrain them with [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) or C++20 [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

To answer your edit: the first version above is exactly how you can use such a parameter pack. Note the expression is `(Ints + ...)` instead of `(args + ...)`.

You can also have a look at [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), particularly the alias `index_sequence` and the examples in that page.

I also found [this specific application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22536207/3854570) for computing fibonacci numbers at compile-time.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not writing a function to sum ints. What you described is the type (2) of parameter pack from the cppreference - "typename|class ... pack-name(optional) (2)" - and I know how to use that type.

Comment: @a_girl The first version is the type (1) you mention in your question. The second version is indeed the type (2), but it's in line with your snippet, with the function having normal parameters.

Comment: my snippet is irrelevant due to my complete lack of understanding of where to use type (1)